# Why won't my citrus trees fruit?

Tags: citrus

I have 6 citrus plants bought from the nursery and it has been in ground for 5 years in full sun and still no flowers nor fruit. How can I get it to fruit

Comment: Hi Ben, can you give us some more information? What kind of citrus? Where in the world are these plants located? Irrigation and fertilization schedule? Anything else you maybe doing? Pictures could be a help too. Just click the "edit" link under your post to add to it. :)

Comment: Are they standard trees? Standards take longer to fruit than dwarfs. And what size were they when they were planted?

Answer (score 5):

Citrus often take five years or more to flower and fruit. Some take more than others.

Overferilizaion with nitrogen can cause some citrus to just be vegetative and not flower.  This can result from you giving the plants too much, or them getting it from your near-by lawn care.  You can avoid the lawn-care situation by not applying lawn fertilizer in the trees' root zone.

Underfertilizing can also result in no flowers.  Make sure you are providing adequate fertilizer for your trees. You usually see other symptoms if you have a deficiency, but it may be 'marginal' and all you see is lack of flowering. Go to your Extension Office or Website and see what they recommend locally.

Nearly any other stress can cause this too.  Too cold is often an issue, but you usually see other damage.  Same with too much or too little water. Hopefully you planted correctly and don't have an issue there (look up how to plant a citrus tree to see if you did it correctly and it still looks like it should).  Your local Extension office will often have this info as well.

Comment: For website, I mean your Extension Service's website. Talking to a real person, however, is often best.  Find the person who really knows Citrus, you may have to dig a bit to find them.